# Use markdown and routerLink together

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, markdown

I have a marked pipe that utilizes a renderer.
On my app users can post links to my app, i want to change the href into a [routerLink]

An incoming url string would be http://localhost:4200/areas/fun/629661722

Heres my current code that does not work

```
export class MarkedPipe implements PipeTransform {
renderer = new marked.Renderer();

constructor() {
this.renderer.link = function( href, title, text ) {
  let url = '<a target="_blank" href="' + href;
  console.log(href)
  if (href.indexOf('localhost:4200') !== -1) {
    console.log(href.substring(21, href.length))
    url = '<a [routerLink]="[\'' + href.substring(21, href.length) + '\']"';
    console.log(url)
  }
  return url + ' title="' + title + '">' + text + '</a>';
};

marked.setOptions({
  renderer: this.renderer,
  sanitize: true
});
}

transform(value: string): string {
return '<span class="markdown">' + marked(value || '') + '</span>';
}
}
```

html code:

```
<span class="mainText" [innerHTML]="post?.text | marked"></span>
```

Comment: The code looks incomplete. Share more code and `.html` code. Also, move `const renderer` outside constructor .

Comment: Moved renderer outside, heres my html code, still doesnt work